# google login GUI in windows forms

Tags: .net, google-chrome, authentication, google-api, google-plus

I made an application that brings you to google login window, using the web browser control in windows forms, all works fine, yet I the GUI is not like how it suppose to be, the form is fixed in size, so I want to make the login window more like auto fit by itself, to know what I mean check the window that appears after clicking the button in this link: https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/build-button

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I just contacted Gmail team, and they replied that this feature isn't available right now for Gmail login page